# jquery.raty stars in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rating, raty

I'm making a tutorial with Mackenzie child for building a movie review app and I got really stuck in the part to add the jquery.raty stars in my project. 
I'd be very thankful if you anyone could spot me a light on what to do to solve my problem as it goes since I've tried several ways and nothing seems to work.
[here's the code I added to application.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqnT3.png)

[this is my show.html.erb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siy91.png)

[this is the error message that comes when I run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyEkQ.png)

Does anyone has any idea of what to do and could help me with any fixer for such? * Of course that I've downloaded and added to the /app/assets/javascripts the jquery.raty.js

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You should have an `app/assets/javascripts/channels` directory (probably with just an empty `.keep` file in it), the error is saying that you don't and part of the Rails JavaScript is looking for one. Posting code as images is generally frowned upon BTW.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks for bring up a fix for the visualisation issue. Now, I'm working on in the visualisation of the stars... any thoughts?